# Clear list but retain Session

Tags: c#, list, session

I have a certain code with list as shown,

```
var refinedClaimSearchNew = new ClaimSearch();
for (int i = 1; i < refineDictionary.Length; i++)
{
    List<ClaimSearchDataValues> claimTable = new List<ClaimSearchDataValues>();
    int count = i; 
    if (count == 1) { claimTable = refinedClaimSearch.RowValues; }
    else { //My problem is in this else loop
           claimTable = (List<ClaimSearchDataValues>)Session["Test"];//Get the list out of session
           if (refinedClaimSearchNew.RowValues != null) { refinedClaimSearchNew.RowValues.Clear(); //And then clear the list but retain session value} 
         }

    var dictionaryItems = refineDictionary[i];
    string[] dictionaryItemsSplit = dictionaryItems.Split(',');

    for (int j = 1; j < dictionaryItemsSplit.Length; j++)
    {
       var nodeElement = dictionaryItemsSplit[j];
       foreach (var row in claimTable)
       {
          var currentRow = row;
          bool hasRefineValue = false;
          foreach (var rowValues in currentRow.CellValues)
          {
              if (rowValues.Key == nodeElement || rowValues.Value == nodeElement)
              {
                  hasRefineValue = true;
              }
          }
          if (hasRefineValue == true)
          {
             refinedClaimSearchNew.RowValues.Add(currentRow);
          }
       }
    }
    Session["Test"] = refinedClaimSearchNew.RowValues;//storing list in session
}
```

I'm storing a list in session and for the next iteration I want to remove the stored list from the session but at the same time clear the list so that I can use the new list again..
But it looks like when I take the list out of session-its fine, the next line when I clear() the list, the list retrieved from the session also becomes 0..
please help me know how to do that....

Comment: `refinedClaimSearchNew.RowValues.Clear()` this is not session can be removed/cleared . use  `Session.clearAll();` add this line in you `else`

Comment: or if you want to clear a particular session then use `Session.remove["session_name"];`